# HandlingChange input REACTJS + TypeScript bug

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export default class triangleArea extends React.Component<triangleInfo> {
    constructor(props:triangleInfo) {
        super(props);

        //initializing variables to undefined
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

  this.state = {
      base: 0,
      height: 0,
      area: undefined,
      error: ""
    };
  }

  //Handling change of input Base and HEIGHT

  handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=> 
  {
       this.setState({
       name : event.target.value
  });
  }//getArea function to calculate Area

  getArea = async (triangleInfo) => {
      triangleInfo.preventDefault();

      const base = triangleInfo.target.elements.base.value;
      const height = triangleInfo.target.elements.height.value;

      if(base > 0 && height > 0)
      {
          this.setState ({
             base: triangleInfo.target.elements.base.value,
             height : triangleInfo.target.elements.height.value,
             area: (base*height)/2
          })
      }
      else
      {
          this.setState ({
              base: undefined,
              height: undefined,
              area: undefined,
              error: "Please enter the values correctly."
          })
      }
  }

render() {
    return (
       //...
      <div>
        <form>
           <p>Calculate the base of a triangle!</p>
           <input type="text" id="base" placeholder = "base" value={this.state.base} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
           <input type="text" id="height" placeholder = "height" value={this.state.height} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
           <button type="submit">Get Area</button>
        </form>
     </div>
    //...
  );
}
};
```

I am currently stuck here, getting this error message:

> Property 'height' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.ts(2339)

Same with the base input. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Where do you call `getArea`?
2. Since you want to reuse the `handleChange` method logic (which is good), you want to parametrise `handleChange` properly by adding an argument that tells which control is it bound to, like this:

```
/* Where the first param could be "base" or "height" */
handleChange = (field: "base" | "height", value) => {
  this.setState({
    [field]: value
  });
  ...

/* and call it in input "onChange" like so: */
 onChange={(e) => this.handleChange("base", e.target.value)}

 // ... do the same for "height" field
```

3. In your code, `triangleInfo` should just be the "type" (in typescript) so you should not access properties from it as if they are values that come from state variables. I think it's definition is like this:

```
type triangleInfo = {
  base: number;
  height: number;
  area: number;
};

/* usage
const t: triangleInfo = { base: 5, height: 6, area: 15 };
*/
```

4. Finally in your `getArea` method, I think you want this called upon submission of the form: `<form onSubmit={this.getArea}>`, also you probably want to use the "current" state values to calculate the "state" `area` instead:

```
// remember that you set state "base" and "height" from your handleChange method.
const { base, height } = this.state;

if(base > 0 && height > 0) {
  this.setState ({
    // you probably only want to calculate area, so you can leave base and height as it is.
    area: (base*height)/2
  })
}
...
```

P.S: In your use case, you don't have to use props, and "triangleInfo" can by used in your "state" instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, now i know how to handle various input changes! However I am still learning and I don't really understand what do you mean on number 3.

Comment: I edited my answer, #3 is `typescript` specific, you should research more on it if you want to use `typescript` in javascript.

Comment: I am using interfaces, interface triangleInfo {
  base: number;
  height: number;
  area: number;
  error: string;
}

Comment: and even if i make do changes I still get the error on the input tag saying that value={base} Cannot find name 'base'.ts(2304)

Comment: Which line? While this deserves a separate issue, SO doesn't like posts with a chat-like conversations in the comment section. Also, try to eliminate "typescript codes" if it helps isolating the issue